# Pandas: Selecting NaN values using np.nan

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So I found out that the float NaN apparently [doesn't equal itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values). My question is how to deal with it. Let's start with a dataframe:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'X':[0, 3, None]})
DF
      X
0   0.0
1   3.0
2   NaN

DF['test1'] = np.where(DF['X'] == np.nan, 1, 0)
DF['test2'] = np.where(DF['X'].isin([np.nan]), 1, 0)
DF
      X test1 test2
0   0.0     0     0
1   3.0     0     0
2   NaN     0     1
```

So test1 and test2 aren't the same. Many others have mentioned that we should use `pd.isnull()`. My question is, is it safe to just use `isin()`? For example, if I need to create a new column using np.where, can I simply do:

```
DF['test3'] = np.where(DF['X'].isin([0, np.nan]), 1, 0)
```

Or should I always use `pd.isnull` like so:

```
DF['test3'] = np.where((DF['X'] == 0) | (pd.isnull(DF['X'])), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Later is marginally fast usually.

Comment: The easiest way to know would be to use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html). In my contrived case of a DF with 10000 entries, your first method is ~10% faster but it might be affected by several factors specific to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `pd.isnull` or `np.isnan` if you suspect there could be `nan`s.

For example suppose you have an `object`-dtype column (unfortunately these aren't uncommon):

```
     X
0    a
1    3
2  NaN
```

Then using `isin` won't give you correct results:

```
>>> df['X'].isin([np.nan])
0    False
1    False
2    False
Name: X, dtype: bool
```

While `isnull` still works correctly:

```
>>> df['X'].isnull()
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: X, dtype: bool
```

Given that `NaN` support isn't explicitly mentioned in [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) nor [`DataFrame.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) it might just be an implementation detail that it correctly "finds" NaNs. And implementation details are always bad to rely on. They could change anytime...

Aside from this, it always pays off to be explicit. An explicit `isnull` or `isnan` check should be (in my opinion) preferred.